# Java regex that handles several possibilites

Tags: java, regex, regex-group

I am trying to find a regex for the following user generated possibilities:

- `÷2%3%x#4%2$@`

OR

- `÷2%x#4%2$@`

OR

- `÷2%x#4$@`

OR

- `÷2%x@`

***To understand the expression***, it is a fraction whose numerator lies between
the `÷` and the first `%`, and the denominator lies from first `%` to the `@`.
But, the denominator has an exponent, which lies from the `#` to `$`.

The **user can input whatever number he/she desires**, **but the structure stays** the same. Notice that the number can also be a decimal.

**The structure is as follows**: ÷(a number, if its two or more digits a % will be in between the digits)x(a group that consists of a number(s), also the symbols # , $ and a %(s) which can also alternate between the digits)@

***Remember, the number can be a decimal number.***

I am trying to use the following regex with no success:

```
"[÷]-?\\d+(\\.\\d*)?[%](-?\\d+(\\.\\d*)?){0,1}[x]([#]-?\\d+(\\.\\d*)?[$]){0,1}[@]"
```

I think that the group `(-?\d+(\.\d*)?){0,1}` is complicating things up. 
Also, I have not accounted for the `%` within this group which could occur.

any suggestions, thank you

Comment: what are valid / invalid inputs?

Comment: Why don't you.... just not use regex?

Comment: what do you mean not use a regex? @user202729

Comment: the valid inputs are the possibilities I listed on top @luk2302

Comment: then dont use a regex, just `input.equals("firstThing") || input.equals("secondThing") || input.equals("thirdThing")`.

Comment: those inputs are user generated. The numbers can change, but the structure will remain the same. @luk2302

Comment: You do know that `{0,1}` is written simpler as `?`, right?

Comment: @i_o are you after something like `[÷\d%[a-zA-z0-9][%#@][a-zA-Z0-9]?[#$%]?[0-9]?[%$]?[0-9@]?[$]?[@]?]` ? You can try it [here](https://regex101.com/r/AF9F75/1).

Comment: @pkpkpk did you test this regex?

Comment: I tested on regex101: https://regex101.com/r/AF9F75/1/

Comment: Why don't you write a parser? Regex is not the good tool for such job.

Comment: @i_o Alternatively if you just want to match any number of those characters you may just use a character class `[÷0-9%x#$@]+` . Try here https://regex101.com/r/AF9F75/2/

Comment: Are all of the parts optional, eg is `÷2%3%x%2$@` OK? Please provide more edge cases for what should match and what should not, plus details of what "no success" means exactly.

Answer (score 0):

**Edit:** Deleted the old post content.

According to your new testcases I improved your regex to match all cases and simplified the regex:

```
÷[0-9%]+?x(#[0-9%]+?\$)?@  OR  ÷[\d%]+?x(#[\d%]+?\$)?@
```

**Note:**

The `[]` mark groups of allowed characters so it has no use to have the parenthesis.

Also `[÷][0-9]+[0-9[%]]+?` is just the same as `÷[0-9]+[0-9%]+?` the first part in your example matches any number `0-9 n-times` and then you check for either `(0-9 or %)` for n-times (non greedy fetching). So instead you can just use the second check for the whole thing.

By wrapping the exponent in a regex-class: `()` we can make the whole exponent optional with `?` ==> this will make your 4th test-case work.

You could also substitute `0-9` with `\d (any digit)` if you want.

Comment: Muller   It did not work for the following input: ÷3%4%x%#2%0$@

Comment: I updated the answer. It would be best if you could write all rules that are possible and put it into your question. I don't know the syntax so it is hard to get it right.

Comment: This matching `÷a_b_c%_%%%%%####@` not sure it is wanted

Comment: @Toto I know. But as long as I don't have any rules for what is valid and what not I cannot improve my answer.

Comment: It works for up to two digit numbers.. then it breaks down with this input: ÷32%2%3%1%x#2%1$@    Muller

Comment: @i_o work out your cases it is impossible as for now to help you out. Provide syntax if you want help. Like this: (number)(% or # exactly 1 time)(number) etc. can you do that in words? would help me a ton.

Comment: it should be like this:  [÷](number)[%](number or numbers with alternating % symbols)[x][#])number or numbers with alternating %)[$][@]    Muller

Comment: @i_o Still unclear and what is x? As long as you don't tell us what exactly you want we can't give you an exact answer. I don't need 3 examples of what works I need just 1 example of how everything works without exception in words like this:
`[number], %(optional), [number], #(required), [number or x] etc.`

Comment: I found a regex that works.. I just tested it will all possibilities up there. I will post it now.  Muller

Comment: Incorrect: *`[÷][0-9]+[0-9[%]]+?` is just the same as `÷[0-9%]+?`*. They are different, because the second allows `%` as the first char, but the first does not.

Comment: @Bohemian You are right. Thanks for the hint. I did not notice. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found a regex that works, I tested from the bottom up:
Here it is:

```
[÷][0-9[%][\\.]]+?[x][0-9[%][\\.][#][$]]*?[@]
```

This regex works for all types of cases. Even those that include decimal numbers, or not exponents.

**the group [0-9[%][\.][#][$]]*?** allows the regex to search for exponent, **which can occur zero(that's why the * is there)** or more times and the ? makes it optional. Similarly, **I followed the same idea** for the coefficient of x(read the post if you don't know where the coefficient lies) and the numerator. Thank you for everyone that put effort in brainstorming this problem. I have chosen to use my answer for my programming.

Comment: Your testcases fail with this one? At least it does for me. Why do you use groups for single characters? Or is this the testcase???

Comment: Try it again.. the only one that will fail is the last test case.  Muller

Comment: And the first test case should not start with a zero. Muller

Comment: The last test case.. will be very easy to overcome. But, the regex above works for all the rest of them.

Comment: Can you show me in regex101 how you matched it? It did not work for me. Not even the first case is a match.

Comment: I see what you are saying.. I agree is not working on this website. I tested it on netbeans IDE, and they all worked except the last one. Muller

Comment: I updated my answer and I found a solution for all your cases. The java regex is a little different then the ones used on 101regex so it did not work. I forgot about that.